# VT500 terminal emulation Flex component

Tags: apache-flex, air, terminal, emulation

Does anybody know of an existing Flex component that does VT500 terminal emulation?

We are gradually replacing terminal-based user interfaces with an AIR-based GUI.
We would like to have a terminal emulator embedded in that new AIR GUI, in order to give our users an integrated user experience when navigating between our old and new software.

Emulation of other VT-series terminals than the VT500 could also be usefull.

Btw, I'm not interested in writing it myself (nor having it written for me) because it would only be a nice-to-have in our software architecture.

Thanks,
Pieter

Comment: Does it have to be such a late standard? That is, do you really use any VT-500 specific features? The only thing VT-500 really has that I know of is ANSI color, and there's a good chance a VT-xxx emulator will support that as an extension for older terminal types.

Comment: Indeed, an emulator for an older VT* standard will probably be good enough. Do you know of any such emulator that is a Flex component?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Isn't the whole point of using Air and upgrading the technology is that you DON'T need to use a terminal anymore?  Seems a bit redundant.

I don't think you'll find anyone that has already created the emulator, but it can't be that hard to implement if you *really* need the functionality.  I know I've seen an AJAX implementation of it (anyterm.org) that uses the [ROTE library](http://rote.sourceforge.net/) for the virtual emulator.  You might want to look into that.

Comment: Well, fact of the matter is that we are _gradually_ upgrading a very large codebase. A big bang transition is unlikely to succeed in our case. That's why we'll our users to be work in a combination of Flex GUI and terminal emulation. And for the sake of navigating and communicating between the two, having a Flex based terminal emulator embedded in the GUI would allow for a better user experience.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the ROTE Library. But I'm afraid porting it to Flex/Actionscript is too big an effort in our situation.

Comment: @Pieter, I understand.  That was kind of the sentiment I wanted to get across.  It would be 'counter-efficient' to create this emulator in Flex just for the hell of keeping compatibility to a legacy way of doing things.  If anything, aim for "blue sky" kind of app and if you customers want to have the terminal, let them use the old app which you still support.